# Get ID of element and display on the page

Tags: javascript

I am not advanced in the Javascript realm, and can't figure out how to write the code to do this.

Basically, I'll use a URL parameter to run this function (&testing) - but I'd like to take the ID of an input field and display it next to that input. I frequently use these ID's for CSS etc, and it would be great to have them auto-display next to a field rather than having to inspect every element individually.

Any help?

Comment: Show us a little of your code...

Comment: Could add the id as a tooltip? the html attribute is title, will appear when you mouseover an element

Comment: `document.getElementById("the_id").value` is the input value. `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML` is the internal html of the element.

Comment: I don't suppose browser developer tools (try pressing F12) actually accomplish this task for you? Usually, you can hover over an element in the Tools' code, and it will highlight the relevant element for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little trickier than it sounds. If you don't want to mess with the IDs, you'll have to

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Which creates a `NodeList` of the input elements. Then, loop through with a simple for loop, or go fancy with a `prototype` call.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function(x) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = x.id;
    x.parentNode.appendChild(x);
});
```

This is a fancy script that creates a span, and assigns the text to the id of the element it's iterating over. It then appends said span after the input by grabbing the parent and `appendChild`ing it.

This assumes your inputs do not share the same parent, so you may have to adjust for your HTML structure, but the key is to iterate, assign text, and append the new element.

Comment: I made a version of what you put together work for my application. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you need any further explanations? I did use some pretty advanced concepts lol

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i =0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].title = inputs[i].id;
}
```

Finds all the html input elements on a page, and adds a tooltip with its id value on mouse over.

Dev tools can do this for you though without causing as much fuss!